# Problems installing LabView Community Edition

Tags: software-installation, login, uninstall

Today I Downloaded the latest LabView Community ISO (My laptop is updated to the latest Ubuntu 20.04) Having done that, I uncompressed the ISO file, executed the INSTALL file with no errors, when I opened LabView, it asked me to verify mi NI account, after logging in, in the browser I get this message: "You have been authenticated. You may close this window." But, the installer said that it couldn't verify my account, so LV wouldn't open, it displayed a message telling me to reinstall, when I tried uninstalling and installing again I broke LabView, now it won't appear as an application, the installation folder isn't there and when I tried reinstalling it, the install file would tell me that it already is installed even when it is nowhere to be found.

I need help addresing both issues, re-installin LabView Community and achieving it to let me start session.

Comment: I think it may have to  do  with the settings that labview stores rather than the program , you might want to check your home directory or lookup where labview stores  its config file and delete that ,then reinstall labview

Comment: I already achieved to uninstall and reinstall LabView, yet the login problem persist. I'll try your recommendation, and update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.
According to national instructions, you must install as root, with su (here I think sudo works).
You must start the program as root (I am using su). Here you may have problems if your default browser is Chrome or Chromium (they have security restrictions as root). I solved this by installing Midori and configuring it as the default browser (sudo update-backups --config x-www-browser). Authentication works with this ...

Answer (score 0):

@Alex is right,This works.
But there are some additional processes need to be done before Labview can start to work.

Procedure:-

1. Install Labview community version into Ubuntu as root (sudo).
2. Install Midori. `sudo apt install midori`
3. Set Midori as the default browser in 'x-www-browser' using this command. `sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser` (Changing default browser in GUI window in settings option does NOT work)
4. Run labview 'very specifically' in sudo -i mode (NOT in 'just' sudo mode).

1. `sudo -i`
2. `labview64`

5. Now the NI login page will appear in the midora browser window.
6. Login and wait for some time
7. Now the Labview will authenticated
8. If the login page takes long time to log into then close the browser after 5min. After you close the browser the Labview will extract the authetication token from the midora cache.
9. Now you can run Labview in sudo mode. `sudo labview64` **NOTE:- You cannot run labview using the icon in application window as this method only authenticates the labview in sudo mode and not in normal mode.**

Now for those interested with the reason for this 'Confusion' with the installation process is that the Labview installation in linux is forced to be done only with elevated permission (sudo or su). But many browsers like chrome and firefox (browser will be automatically opened by Labview)will not run in sudo mode. This combination of restrictions complicates the whole process of authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the help. With the knowledge that the initial activation works when running as the superuser, I was able to figure out an improved method that enables it to work as a non-root user. This also eliminates the need to install the Midori browser.

Answer (score 0):

@Neeraj's instructions were a big help; for some reason, running it as root did allow it to activate when it wouldn't otherwise. But the actual method I used was a bit different, and I also managed to get it to run as a non-root user, which should be encouraged as it's bad security practice to run programs as root unless they actually need administrative privileges.

This is the process I used:

1. Install LabVIEW.
2. Run LabVIEW **without** sudo and attempt to activate it.
3. If you get the "You have been authenticated" page, but it fails to activate, close LabVIEW but keep the page open.
4. Run `sudo -i` to get a root shell, and from there, `labview64`.
5. When you get the activation prompt, go back to your web browser and refresh the "You have been authenticated" page. It should be activated now; if not, you might need to click the "Activate" button (which would normally open the browser) and try refreshing that same tab again.
6. Quit LabVIEW. In the root shell, do `cp ~/natinst/.config/LabVIEW-2021/.lvce.2021.lc ~USER/natinst/.config/LabVIEW-2021/`, and then `chown USER:USER ~USER/natinst/.config/LabVIEW-2021/.lvce.2021.lc`. Replace every instance of "`USER`" (in both commands) with your username.

After following these steps, I was then able to run LabVIEW without sudo.